# calling static methods of a templated superclass

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, static-methods

I have a templated class `A<T>` that contains a static method `foo()` that returns an `A<T> *`.  I have a subclass `B` which simply specializes to `A<int>`.

To avoid code duplication, I'd like B to take advantage of A's static `foo()` method.  However, the following gets a compilation error: `error: cannot initialize return object of type 'B *' with an rvalue of type 'A<int> *')`  But `B *` is exactly `A<int> *`, no?

Is there a way for B to use A's `foo()` method?

```
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
  static A *foo() {
    // imagine complex code here
    return new A<T>();
  }
};

// B is a typed specialization of A
class B : public A<int> {
public:
  static B *foo() {
    return A<int>::foo();    // doesn't compile
  }
};

int main() {
  B *b = B::foo();
  (void)b;                      // suppress unused variable warning
}
```

Comment: `I'd like B to take advantage of A's static foo() method`, `A::foo()` is public, why would you duplicate it in `B`?

Comment: Because I've omitted details to keep the example simple: `B::foo()` does some additional things to the object returned by `A::foo()`.

Comment: _" But B * is exactly A<int> *, no?"_ Well, no! Not at all. `B` is _not_ a specialisation of `A`. `A<int>` is a specialisation of `B`. `B` is a class that inherits from `A<int>`. It's a distinct type.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to create a class `B` that, when I use it, means `A<int>`?

If `B` is an alias for `A<int>`, then it's an alias for `A<int>`, and `B::foo` and `A<int>::foo` are the same thing, and what you really want is for `A<int>::foo` to do something extra compared to vanilla `A<T>::foo`, but still reuses `A<T>::foo`'s code.

In other words, you need an explicit specialization for that member function. To reuse the vanilla version of the code, just move the common code to a separate function:

```
template<class T>
struct A {
    static A<T> * foo_common() { 
        // common stuff 
        return nullptr;     
    }

    static A<T> * foo() { 
        // vanilla foo(); just call foo_common()
        return foo_common(); 
    }
};

// specialization of `foo` for A<int>
template<>
inline A<int>* A<int>::foo() { 
    auto p = foo_common(); 
    // extra stuff
    return p;
}
```

And if you want `B` to mean `A<int>`, it's straightforward:

```
using B = A<int>;
```